# Laravel: How to move a new line when the value is not the same as the previous value, foreach in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

When doing the looping process, I want to compare when the current value is not the same as the previous value, then move a new line.

```
--------------------------
|unique_id| name | stats |
--------------------------
|1        | A    | P     |
|1        | B    | P     |
|1        | C    | P     |
|2        | D    | P     |
--------------------------
```

This is my code in blade:

```
@foreach ($result as $item)
  {{ $item->stats}}
@endforeach
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `$previousstatus` outside of `foreach`. once the `foreach` run the variable will set the value of current `status` that'll help to you in the next run.

```
@php $previousstatus = ''; @endphp
@foreach ($result as $item)

 //@if($previousstatus == $item->stats) @endif do as you want with previousstatus

  {{ $item->stats}}

 @php $previousstatus =  $item->stats; @endphp //set the status for next loop becuase we need to remember in next loop what was the last element so store it in temp(previousstatus ) varible,

@endforeach
```